# main menu is affecting my sub menu

Tags: css, navbar, nav

I am trying to separate css for all aspects of the menu as its affecting the sub menu on hover. What am I missing? Whenever I mouse over the sub menu I'm getting background color and the pic is being altered. How can I separate the css for the top menu and the sub menu without the effects bleeding over?

How can I separate the css effect of main li hover and the ul li ul li a on hover? or at least make it so the effects on the main li don't affect the sub menu li on hover?

```css
nav#menu{
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  width:100%;
  height:px;
  position: relative;
  top:50px;
  background-color:blue;
}
.js nav[role=navigation] { 
  width:100%;
  height:px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
nav[role=navigation] ul { 
  margin: 0 0 0 -0.25em;
  border: 0;
}
nav[role=navigation]  li {
  padding:5px;
  position: relative; 
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0.10em;
}
nav#menu li > a:hover{
  padding:5px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background-color:#666;
  color:#A10115;
}  
nav[role=navigation] li a {
  border:0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#F0EFEA;
  font-size:1.5em;
}
ul li ul.dropdown{
  min-width:800px; /* Set width of the dropdown */
  background-color:#666;
  padding:10px;
  display: none;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  left: -40px;
}
ul li:hover ul.dropdown{
  display: block; /* Display the dropdown */
}
ul li ul.dropdown li{
  border: 3px solid red;      
}
ul li ul.dropdown li a{
  background-color:yellow;
}


    #lilab{
        background-color: yellow;
        width:100%;
        height:20px;
    }
      #liinfo{
       text-align: center;
            font-size:10px; line-height: 1.5;
    }
    
      li#central{
text-align: center; 
height:100px;
width:100px;
background-color:red;background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
        
    }
        li#north{text-align: center; 
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
background-color:red;background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
        
    }
        li#east{text-align: center;
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
background-color:red;background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;

        
    }
            li#west{text-align: center;
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
        background-color:red;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
        
    }
            li#south{text-align: center;
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
background-color:red;background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
        
    }
```

```html
<nav id="menu" role="navigation">

            
      <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li> 
    <li><a href="index.html">Locations</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
    <li id="central"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">Central</div><div id="liinfo">adress 1</div></a></li>
    <li id="north"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">North</div><div id="liinfo">adress 2</div></a></li>
    <li id="east"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">East</div><div id="liinfo">adress 3</div></a></li>
    <li id="west"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">West</div><div id="liinfo">adress 4</div></a></li>
    <li id="south"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">South</div><div id="liinfo">adress 5</div></a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
            
      <li><a href="index.html">Contacts</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Services</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
    <li id="central"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">Central</div><div id="liinfo">
    address5</div></a></li>
    <li id="north"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">North</div><div id="liinfo">
    address4</div></a></li>
    <li id="east"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">East</div><div id="liinfo">
    address3</div></a></li>
    <li id="west"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">West</div><div id="liinfo">
    address2</div></a></li>
    <li id="south"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">South</div><div id="liinfo">
    address1</div></a></li>
    </ul>
            
            
            </li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Media</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Partners</a></li>
             <li><a href="index.html">Things to Know</a></li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple solution to this. `nav#menu li > a:hover` is selecting all li elements within `nav#menu`. All you have to do is add `>` between `nav#menu` and `li` like so `nav#menu > li > a:hover`. The `>` means it is a direct child. So grandchildren would not be included. Here's a good article on child and sibling selectors [child/sibling selectors](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/).

```css
nav#menu{
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  width:100%;
  height:px;
  position: relative;
  top:50px;
  background-color:blue;
}
.js nav[role=navigation] { 
  width:100%;
  height:px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
nav[role=navigation] ul { 
  margin: 0 0 0 -0.25em;
  border: 0;
}
nav[role=navigation]  li {
  padding:5px;
  position: relative; 
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0.10em;
}
nav#menu > li > a:hover{
  padding:5px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background-color:#666;
  color:#A10115;
}  
nav[role=navigation] li a {
  border:0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#F0EFEA;
  font-size:1.5em;
}
ul li ul.dropdown{
  min-width:800px; /* Set width of the dropdown */
  background-color:#666;
  padding:10px;
  display: none;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  left: -40px;
}
ul li:hover ul.dropdown{
  display: block; /* Display the dropdown */
}
ul li ul.dropdown li{
  border: 3px solid red;      
}
ul li ul.dropdown li a{
  background-color:yellow;
}


    #lilab{
        background-color: yellow;
        width:100%;
        height:20px;
    }
      #liinfo{
       text-align: center;
            font-size:10px; line-height: 1.5;
    }
    
      li#central{
text-align: center; 
height:100px;
width:100px;
background-color:red;background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
        
    }
        li#north{text-align: center; 
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
background-color:red;background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
        
    }
        li#east{text-align: center;
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
background-color:red;background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;

        
    }
            li#west{text-align: center;
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
        background-color:red;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
        
    }
            li#south{text-align: center;
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
background-color:red;background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
        
    }
```

```html
<nav id="menu" role="navigation">

            
      <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li> 
    <li><a href="index.html">Locations</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
    <li id="central"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">Central</div><div id="liinfo">adress 1</div></a></li>
    <li id="north"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">North</div><div id="liinfo">adress 2</div></a></li>
    <li id="east"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">East</div><div id="liinfo">adress 3</div></a></li>
    <li id="west"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">West</div><div id="liinfo">adress 4</div></a></li>
    <li id="south"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">South</div><div id="liinfo">adress 5</div></a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
            
      <li><a href="index.html">Contacts</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Services</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
    <li id="central"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">Central</div><div id="liinfo">
    address5</div></a></li>
    <li id="north"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">North</div><div id="liinfo">
    address4</div></a></li>
    <li id="east"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">East</div><div id="liinfo">
    address3</div></a></li>
    <li id="west"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">West</div><div id="liinfo">
    address2</div></a></li>
    <li id="south"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">South</div><div id="liinfo">
    address1</div></a></li>
    </ul>
            
            
            </li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Media</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Partners</a></li>
             <li><a href="index.html">Things to Know</a></li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```css
 nav#menu{
  width:100%;
  height:px;
  position: relative;
  top:50px;
  background-color:blue;
 }
 
 .js nav[role=navigation] { 
  width:100%;
  height:px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
  
 nav[role=navigation] ul { 
  margin: 0 0 0 -0.25em;
  border: 0;
 }

 nav[role=navigation]  li {
  padding:5px;
  position: relative; 
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0.10em;
 }
 
 nav#menu li > a{
  padding: 5px;
 }
 nav#menu li > a:hover{
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  color:#A10115;
 }  
 
 nav[role=navigation] li a {
  border:0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#F0EFEA;
  font-size:1.5em;
 }
 
 ul li ul.dropdown{
  min-width:800px; /* Set width of the dropdown */
  background-color:#666;
  padding:10px;
  display: none;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  left: -40px;
 }
 
 ul li:hover ul.dropdown{
  display: block; /* Display the dropdown */
 }
 
 #lilab{
  background-color: yellow;
  width:100%;
 }
 
 #liinfo{
  text-align: center;
  font-size:10px; line-height: 1.5;
 }

 li#central{
  text-align: center; 
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:red;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
 }
 
 li#north{text-align: center; 
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:red;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
 }
 
 li#east{text-align: center;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:red;background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
 }
 
 li#west{text-align: center;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:red;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
 }
 
 li#south{text-align: center;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:red;background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
 }
```

```html
 <nav id="menu" role="navigation">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li> 
   <li><a href="index.html">Locations</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
     <li id="central"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">Central</div><div id="liinfo">adress 1</div></a></li>
     <li id="north"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">North</div><div id="liinfo">adress 2</div></a></li>
     <li id="east"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">East</div><div id="liinfo">adress 3</div></a></li>
     <li id="west"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">West</div><div id="liinfo">adress 4</div></a></li>
     <li id="south"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">South</div><div id="liinfo">adress 5</div></a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
      
   <li><a href="index.html">Contacts</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.html">Services</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
     <li id="central"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">Central</div><div id="liinfo">address5</div></a></li>
     <li id="north"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">North</div><div id="liinfo">address4</div></a></li>
     <li id="east"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">East</div><div id="liinfo">address3</div></a></li>
     <li id="west"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">West</div><div id="liinfo">address2</div></a></li>
     <li id="south"><a href="#"><div id="lilab">South</div><div id="liinfo">address1</div></a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="index.html">Media</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.html">Partners</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.html">Things to Know</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
```